# modrewrite alter 1 element of query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Flash movies are called based on dynamic links on `mypage.php`.  `mypage.php` has the flash player embedded.  The links look like `mypage.php?moviefolder=folder1/folder2&swfTitle=sometitle.swf`.  `mypage.php` is parsed on each link click (per the href).  `Folder2` is always the same but `movieTitle.swf` is dynamic.  Sometimes subfolders will be called (`folder2/subfolder2/sometitle.swf`).

Can mod_rewrite allow the query string to reflect folder2 but instead silently serve `folder3` as well as occasional subfolders?  I would place all files in folder3. The goal is to have the user not know where the swfs are.  Thanks in advance again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `RewriteCond` to match the contents of the query string (since they are not read in a `RewriteRule` directive, you can extract `swfTitle=sometitle.swf` and substitute `folder1/folder3` for `folder1/folder2` in the `moviefolder`.

This will use a regex pattern like `([^&]+)` to match everything up to the next `&` (which denotes another query param).

```
# Capture everything after folder2 into %1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} moviefolder=folder1/folder2([^&]+) [NC]
# Capture everything in the swfTitle param into %2
# Both conditions must be matched...
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} swfTitle=([^&]+) [NC]
# Then silently rewrite mypage.php to substitute folder3,
# and pass in the original swfTitle captured above
RewriteRule ^mypage\.php$ mypage.php?moviefolder=folder1/folder3%1&swfTitle=%2 [L]
```

Hopefully, you won't get a rewrite loop, since the rewritten `folder1/folder3` won't match the second time.  `[NC]` allows for a case-insensitive match.

I did manage to successfully test this over at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, using the sample input:

```
http://example.com/mypage.php?swfTitle=thetitle.swf&moviefolder=folder1/folder2/thing
---> http://example.com/mypage.php?moviefolder=folder1/folder3/thing&swfTitle=thetitle.swf

http://example.com/mypage.php?moviefolder=folder1/folder2/thing999zzz&swfTitle=thetitle.swf
---> http://example.com/mypage.php?moviefolder=folder1/folder3/thing999zzz&swfTitle=thetitle.swf
```

Comment: Michael, thank you.  I'll try it out and get back to you.  Tks again.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've tried to get this to work for hours and I can't seem to do it.  I'm sure it worked for you and I thank you for your assistance with this.  I'll give a checkmark because I believe it will work, I just think the issue on my end is the way I dynamically get and name the movies.  Once again - thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @ereginator If you give an example of a url that fails, and how it fails, I might be able to troubleshoot a litt.e

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the delay.  I'm not sure that's possible in this forum as I would need a lot more space to explain the code and how it comes to be on the page.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've been trying various ways to figure out what I want to do but still can't do it.  Perhaps this is a better way to explain:
Here is the URL:
mysite.com/folder1/somefile.php or mysite.com/folder1/subfolder/somefile.php

I want anyone who has 'folder1' anywhere in the URL to be redirected to mysite.com/forbidden.php

The rule must only apply if the URL shows 'folder1' but should not prevent access to the directory from mysite.com since 'folder1' contains all the resources that pages will use.

Can this be done?

Comment: OK, so this worked in .htaccess in folder:
http://localhost/mysite.com/Sites/public_html/folder1/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.php$ http://localhost/mysite.com/Sites/public_html/3_error/gotkicked.php [R,L]

the problem is that it only seems to work on the file.  if i try to substitute folder1 in place of test.php, the rewrite does not work.

Comment: @ereginator Wait what? Perhaps I'm too tired but I'm having a hard time parsing what you have in your comment. This seems not entirely related to your original question. If you have a new one, go ahead and ask a new question, and you can ping me here with a link to it.

Comment: Here you are sir:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328487/htaccess-redirect-if-folder-name-in-url