# .htaccess redirect if folder name in url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

using .htaccess, I'm looking to redirect a URL from one folder to another.

For example, if a user requests 'forbiddenFolder' `http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/subfolder`

or

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.php` or

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.swf` or

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.f4v`.

they should be redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/forbidden.php`

I don't want to lockdown the directory itself since there are resources there that are required.  The redirect should only work based on the URL string OR if the user creates a script from www.anothersite.com and leeches files from http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder

I believe rewrite conditions should be implemented....?

Comment: Do you have links to these files on your own site which must be allowed by HTTP referrer?

Comment: yes, but they'll never appear in the URL.  They're accessed via includes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews                                        
RewriteEngine On                                                           
RewriteBase /                                                              
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/forbiddenFolder     [NC]                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /[\w]+\.(php|swf|f4v) [NC,OR]                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /[^.]+/?$             [NC]                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !forbidden\.php       [NC]                     
RewriteRule .*              /forbidden.php        [L,NC]
```

Maps internally

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/subfolder`         or

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.php`      or

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.swf`      or

`http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.f4v`

To:

`http://www.mysite.com/forbidden.php`

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L,NC]` with `[R=301,L,NC]`

---

#### OPTION

With a modified incoming URL structure.

For example:

`http://localhost/trafficticket.tv/Sites/public_html/forbiddenFolder/somefile.swf`

Replace the previous block of rules with this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews                                        
RewriteEngine On                                                           
RewriteBase /                                                              
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /forbiddenFolder      [NC]                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /[\w]+\.(php|swf|f4v) [NC,OR]                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /[^.]+/?$             [NC]                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !forbidden\.php       [NC]                     
RewriteRule .* /trafficticket.tv/Sites/public_html/forbidden.php [L,NC]
```

To use any other URL, the only requirement is to prepend the correct segment path to `/forbidden.php` in the rewrite rule. In this case, that segment is

`/trafficticket.tv/Sites/public_html`

but it could be anything or nothing, like in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Can you please tell me what is the purpose of "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /[^.]+/?$   [NC]" ...not sure I understand this line.  tk u

Comment: That's to make sure the rule also applies when this `http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/subfolder` condition is met.

Comment: right! - tk you so much.  Between yourself and @MichaelBerkowski I'm starting to learn how mod_rewrite works.  The most difficult part is that it works or fails, but unlike php or other programming language, it doesn't explain where/why.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but I tested this solution and it does not work at all.  It as if there was no .htaccess file at all.  I know .htaccess is being read since one of the directives is " IndexIgnore * ", which results in no listing of files within the folder.  But, when the url is pointed to http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.swf, the file plays without issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: If there are more directives, it would be useful to know the whole .htaccess file. Write some garbage to be sure it's being parsed. Make sure mod_rewrite module is enabled. It's really important the URL structure of the request keeps the pattern in your question: `http://www.mysite.com/forbiddenFolder/somefile.swf` not `http://www.mysite.com/Otherfolder/folder/somefile.swf`, for example. For testing, replace [NC,L] flags with [R,NC,L] to **see** the redirected URLs, and make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test. I am sure the rule-set works fine and that's not the problem.

Comment: Thanks Faa.  I put junk in the .htaccess file and I received a 500 server error.  It appears the address locally is the issue as it's: http://localhost/trafficticket.tv/Sites/public_html/forbiddenFolder

On the live site, your solution will no doubt work.

I'm going to play with it and see if I can tweak it so it works locally.  Tk u again.

Comment: @ereginator Added one option to my answer showing how to modify the rule to match a different incoming URL structure, like the one in your last comment.

Comment: Hi faa, thanks so much for all this.  On the live server, it works very well with one exception as follows:

It works here:
http://localhost/trafficticket.tv/Sites/public_html/forbiddenFolder/somefile.swf

But not here:
http://localhost/trafficticket.tv/Sites/public_html/forbiddenFolder/dd/somefile.swf

The 'dd' portion can be anything such as 'dd', 'ed', 'gg' etc.  Those will constantly be added as new content is added.  Some will actually have subfolders: 'ss/0345/somefile.swf'.

So, to complete this question, I presume each dd folder will need its own .htaccess file slightly modified?

Comment: Okay. The rule-set matches any URL like the one you describe: `http://.../forbiddenFolder/dd/ss/0345/somefile.swf`, for example, which means the rule is being applied even in those cases. I guess the problem is with the script that assumes all requests are for video files in the `/forbiddenFolder` directory, for example. Can't suggest anything else as I don't know how does the script to identify the files, as their paths are not being passed in the rule. So no, I don't think having one .htaccess file in each `/forbiddenFolder` sub-directory would solve anything in this case.